# IE11 - XMLHttpRequest level 2 onprogress event not triggered if chunk data bigger than 4kiB

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, xmlhttprequest-level2

I'm using **XMLHTTPRequest** level 2 to keep a sticky connection with the server.

In IE10, Chrome and Firefox, every data chunk received is triggering the **onprogress** event as expected. However, on IE11, if the data chunk has more than 4kiB, the event is not triggered for that chunk.  It will only be triggered after I receive something else.

I've implemented a workaround that sends a dummy data after 0.5 seconds if the previous chunk was bigger than 4k, so the onprogress is triggered for the dummy data and I can retrieve the desired data.

**I would like to know:** the real IE11 behavior regarding the onprogress to make sure if there is a better fix for this issue or if the workaround is actually the right fix.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested some other events like "readystatechange", "load" or "loadend"? If so, I think there is no many things to do once that IE handles weirdly some events. Depending of the code that is running on server, it could cause some side effects on back-end side.